# Test code for the new standard Order object

Tags: unit-test, pricebook, failing-tests, order

The last line **`insert ordPd`** causes exception: **`System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Price Book Not Set on Order: []`**

All lines before the last line are all ok, and have confirmed again and again.

Have tried whatever I can do, still can't resolve the problem. It seems the pricebook and order are not related, however, they should be related by the last 2 line.

Also, Have done research and use 'SeeAllData=true' tag.

The code:

```
Account acct = new Account(Name='tAccount');
insert acct;

Contract ct = new Contract();
ct.AccountId = acct.Id;
ct.Status = 'Draft';
ct.StartDate = Date.Today();
ct.ContractTerm = 12;
insert ct;

ct.Status = 'Activated';
update ct;

Order od = new Order();
od.Name = '14TPE000001';
od.AccountId = acct.Id;
od.EffectiveDate = Date.Today();
od.ContractId = ct.Id;
od.Status = 'Draft';
insert od;

Product2 pd = new Product2(Name='Pord A',isActive=true);
pd.IsActive = true;
insert pd;

PriceBook2 pb2Standard = [select Id from Pricebook2 where isStandard=true];
Id standardPriceBookId = pb2Standard.Id;

PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry(Pricebook2Id=standardPriceBookId, Product2Id=pd.Id, UnitPrice=99, isActive=true);
insert pbe;
Product2 p2ex = [SELECT Name FROM Product2 WHERE Id = :pd.Id];
System.assertEquals(pd.Name,p2ex.Name);

OrderItem ordPd = new OrderItem(PriceBookEntryId=pbe.Id, OrderId=od.Id, Quantity=1, UnitPrice=99);
insert ordPd;
```

Comment: When Summer '14 comes out you will not have to use SeeAllData=true anymore.  There is a new method that will get you the standard pricebook Id: [`Test.getStandardPricebookId() `](http://peterknolle.com/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable `od` must have it's `Pricebook2Id` set before inserting the record. This the same design functionality as the Opportunity and Quote objects.

Comment: Yes, that's it.... too stupid I am

Comment: @CrayKao It's just a learning curve. You'll get there.

Comment: i also facing same problem
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Price Book Not Set on Order: []

but i dont have a Pricebook2Id field in order object . how to resolve this error?

Comment: @nagarjuna You should probably check for existing questions on this, but you definitely should have a Pricebook2Id field on Order (it may not be listed specifically as such on the GUI, but it should exist).

Comment: There appear to be several comments that the Order.Pricebook2Id field isn't always available. I've reworked a [newer question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/40081/field-integrity-exception-price-book-not-set-on-order-at-the-time-of-inser) to deal with this separately.

Answer (score 1):

The minimum working test code:

```
PriceBook2 pb2Standard = [select Id from Pricebook2 where isStandard=true];
Id standardPriceBookId = pb2Standard.Id;

PricebookEntry pbe = [ SELECT Id,Product2Id,Pricebook2Id,UnitPrice FROM PricebookEntry WHERE Pricebook2Id = :standardPriceBookId AND isActive=true LIMIT 1 ];

Order od = [ SELECT Id,Pricebook2Id FROM Order LIMIT 1 ];
od.Pricebook2Id = pb2Standard.Id;
update od;

OrderItem ordPd = new OrderItem(PriceBookEntryId=pbe.Id, OrderId=od.Id, Quantity=1, UnitPrice=pbe.UnitPrice, ServiceDate=Date.Today());
insert ordPd;
```

The last 3-5 lines are key to resolve the problem.

Ref: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_orderitem.htm