# Invalid field Pricebook2Id for SObject Order. Can't set Price book for Order

Tags: pricebook, order

I want to insert the [OrderItem](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_orderitem.htm) object using [Order](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_order.htm), Pricebook2 and PricebookEntry. I retrieved the standard Pricebook2 and inserted an Order and pricebookentry.

At the time of inserting the "OrderItem" it throws the exception as:

> Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
>   FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Price Book Not Set on Order: []

My Code is:

```
List<Account> acclist = [SELECT Id,Name FROM Account WHERE Name='Testname'];
List<Product2> lstproduct = [SELECT Id,Name FROM Product2 WHERE Name='Test'];
Pricebook2 pbook = [select id from Pricebook2 where IsStandard = true limit 1];
String Quantity = '3';

Order obj=new Order();
obj.AccountId  = acclist[0].Id;
obj.EffectiveDate = Date.today();
obj.Status ='Draft';
//obj.Pricebook2Id = pbook.Id; // Results in "Invalid field Pricebook2Id for SObject Order"
System.debug('OBJ####'+obj);
insert obj;

PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry();
pbe.Pricebook2Id = pbook.Id;
pbe.Product2Id = lstproduct[0].id;
pbe.IsActive = true;
pbe.UnitPrice = 110.0;
insert pbe;

OrderItem oobj=new OrderItem();
oobj.PricebookEntryId =pbe.Id;
oobj.OrderId = obj.Id;
oobj.Quantity = Integer.ValueOf(Quantity);

insert oobj;
```

As per, [Test code for the new standard Order object](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34863/test-code-for-the-new-standard-order-object), if the following line is added before the `insert obj;` line:

```
obj.Pricebook2Id = pbook.Id;
```

the following error is returned:

> Invalid field Pricebook2Id for SObject Order

Comment: possible duplicate of [Test code for the new standard Order object](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34863/test-code-for-the-new-standard-order-object)

Comment: @Daniel Ballinger, I view that post  "Test code for the new standard Order object" in that post they mention PriceBook2Id field in Order object but in my sandbox PriceBook2Id field is not available in Order object, Is there any other way to findout the PriceBook2Id field in order object.

Comment: What happens if you add `obj.Pricebook2Id = pbook.Id;` before `insert obj;'? The Order.Pricebook2Id field appears in the [docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_order.htm) as required.

Comment: It Shows "Invalid field Pricebook2Id for SObject Order"

Comment: I've reworked your question to make it clearer that you can't set the required Pricebook2Id for the Order SObject.

Comment: @Daniel Ballinger, Thank you for your support.Is there any other possibilities to insert OrderItem object without using Pricebook2Id field in Order object?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15003/discussion-between-venkatsforce-and-daniel-ballinger).

Comment: @DanielBallinger Thanks for your assistance, now its working, I changed the version of my apexclass from 26.0 to 28.0 then it accepts the PriceBook2Id field in Order object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the API Version of your Test-Class to 28.0 (or higher). That worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for your support @FellowDeveloper, now its working.

Comment: Good catch. This is something to watch out for if you are using an IDE that hasn't been updated to the latest release or the test class meta.xml has an older version in it.